# How to execute a JS code after some seconds in Cordova ?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to execute/run this code `adSetter();` after 5 seconds. This code is in the deviceReady function. The whole code is written in Javascript and using Cordova paltform.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    adSetter();
}, 5000);
```

The code above will wait 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) before executing.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // Do staff here
}, 5000);
```

Comment: What's ``Use timeout function``? I thought cordova supported native js.

Comment: Cordova is a  platform to build native mobile applications using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. So you are free to use native javascript functions.